# Set of points A that are differentiable using the complex function $f(z) = |z|^{2}+e^{-5z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have to check if this function is differentiable one of the following conditions:
$ A=\{(0,0)\} $ or $ A=\{\text{z } \in \text{ C: }|z|=1 \} $.

To the first condition, I have verified it's differentiable using Cauchy-Riemann theorem to $f(z) = x^{2} + y^{2} + e^{-5x}(\cos(5y)-i*\sin(5y))$, following:

$\qquad \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}= 2x - 5 e^{-5x}\cos(5y) \qquad \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}= - 5 e^{-5x}\cos(5y)$

$\qquad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}= 2y - 5 e^{-5x}\sin(5y) \qquad -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}= - 5 e^{-5x}\sin(5y)$

Throught this I can conclude that $x=0$ and $y=0$ satisfy the theorem.

However, to the second condition, I supposed that $x^{2}$ and $y^{2}$ are any constants that respect $|z|^{2} = 1$. Thus, I have analyzed the Cauchy-Riemann to  $f(z) = 1+e^{-5z}$ and it also respected the differentiability to $f(z) = 1 + e^{-5x}(\cos(5y)-i*\sin(5y))$:

$\qquad \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}= - 5 e^{-5x}\cos(5y) \qquad \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}= - 5 e^{-5x}\cos(5y)$

$\qquad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}= - 5 e^{-5x}\sin(5y) \qquad -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}= - 5 e^{-5x}\sin(5y)$

It looks like is not correct to me that this second conditions is differentiable because by the first condition we confirmed that it's only differentiable at $\{0,0\}$. However, I can't understand why my assumption to the second condition is wrong and how I can show that is not differentiable at $|z|$ equal to any constant.

I appreciate very much any help since I couldn't find errors or explanations myself.

Comment: The function $g(z) = e^{-5z}$ is differentiable so it suffices only to look at $h(z) = |z|^2$.

Comment: Your assumption in the second case is wrong because $|z|^2$ and 1 are different functions (with different behaviours), even if their values coincide on the unit circle.

Comment: Desperado is correct. The function $z \mapsto 1+e^{-5z}$ has no relevance for your problem.

Comment: I see what you all are saying. I'm convinced and agree about it, but it only remains one doubt: as Desperado said, since the value of the unit circle coincides with 1, couldn't I say that restricting the complex plane to a circle of limited radius we should have $f(z)$ differentiable at all this limited complex plane through all paths? If it is true,  if I don't restrict the complex plane, the complex plane is infinite and couldn't be differentiable  through all paths, and thus it's differentiable just at {0,0} as the first condition says.  I know that we are mainly speaking about $|z|^{2}$.

Comment: *"restricting the complex plane to a circle of limited radius"* --- what circle are you thinking of? You mean the circle $|z|=1\;$?

Comment: I mean for example the $|z|=1$. I wrote _"circle of limited radius"_ because any |z| equal to a constant would do the same effect at the Cauchy-Riemann equations that I exhibited earlier, right? I mean that the same condition will appear to any fixed |z|.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I am following your idea. Maybe your idea is to restrict the domain of your function to the circumference of some $|z|=R>0\,$? But then the function is a constant function in this restricted domain; nothing interesting is happening.

Comment: Yes, my idea is to restrict the domain using $|z|=R>0$ and by doing this my doubt is: is the function $f(z)=|z|^{2}+e^{−5z}$ differentiable in this restrict domain only on its closure?  In fact, I'm not trying to find something interesting, I'm just curious to know what is happening in case I restrict the complex space: the function will be differentiable only on its closure or will be differentiable on the entire restrict complex plane? Am I understanding the restricting condition correctly? Thank you very much for your patience.

Comment: *only on its closure* - - - I don't know what you mean. (You don't mean the topological closure.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131380/discussion-between-julia-c-leite-and-311411).

Answer (score 2):

The function $z\mapsto|z|^2$ is differentiable at $0$ and only at $0$; the function $z\mapsto e^{-5z}$ (it's the composition of two differentiable functions) is differentiable everywhere. Therefore, their sum is differentiable at $0$ and only at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

When using the Cauchy-Riemann theorem it is possible to lose sight of the basic idea of derivative. We still are considering whether a difference quotient converges at a fixed $z_0=(x_0,y_0),$ with $x_0^2+y_0^2=1.$ We examine

$$\frac{\Delta w}{\Delta z}\,=\,\frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h}\,=\,\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0},$$
where $z=z_0+h$ is a varying vector that might point in any direction from $z_0=(x_0,y_0).$

Hence there is no reason to think that $|z|^2=x^2+y^2$ is equal to one. In fact, it is important to remember that $|z|^2$ is a varying quantity.

As pointed out in the comments, it is enought to show that $h(z)=|z|^2$ does not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann PDEs at any $z_0=(x_0,y_0) \not=(0,0)$.